# Elfinder need to get file hash in PHP

Tags: php, elfinder

I am doing some custom work on elfinder plugin and I want to be able to get hash of file based of the file name or file path.
In my connector PHP file I am using the accessControl callback to a custom function that gets created like this: `function access($attr, $path, $data, $volume) {`. Can i use `$path` variable of this function to get file hash string?
I know that elfinder has a custom way of getting the file hash, I see that I can get the `file.hash` on javascript pretty easy but I need to access it in PHP based on file/folder path. Is there a PHP function that I can call from here to get the file hash?

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

EDIT: Here's some info from Elfinder docs at https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-Server-API-2.0 :

> New 2.x PHP connector uses the following algorithm to create hash from
>   file path:
>
> ```
> remove root path from file path
> encrypt resulting path so it could be later decrypted (not implemented yet, but stub is present)
> encode already encrypted path using base64 with replacement +/= -> -_.
> remove trailing dots
> add prefix - unique volume id (must start with [a-z])
> resulting string must be valid HTML id attribute (that is why base64 is used).
> ```
>
> Using this algorithm even without encryption, client cannot get real
>   file paths on the server only relative to root paths. This hash
>   algorithm is recommended but you can use your own implementation so
>   long as it matches these 2 rules:
>
> ```
> hash must be valid for storage in the id attribute of an HTML tag
> hash must be reversible by connector
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Is it good even elFinder 2.1? elFinder 2.1.3+ will have `$volume->getHash($path, $name)`.

- https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/blob/47be3cd34548d028557754df38cc1f7f9b05b581/php/elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php#L1019-L1031

Please try nightly build. - https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/archive/2.1-src.zip

Answer (score 0):

If $path is the full path to the file, you should be able to do something like this:

```
md5(file_get_contents($path))
```

or

```
hash('sha256', file_get_contents($path))
```

In PHP the hash functions take the file as a string, so you use file_get_contents to get the file as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hoping I could use the internal functions of Elfinder to reach same `$path` encryption procedure. Looking at the Elfinder documentation (https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-Server-API-2.0) we can see a brief of procedures followed so I was hoping I could use the same. Question updated with elfinder doc.